# Cakephp inside a folder not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have XAMPP installed om my local machine. I have put cake in htdocs in a folder cake.
when i hit url localhost/cake/
it seeks cake controller missing.
for this i have tried to change .htaccess file in the folder as suggested by many as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /cake
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But this is not helping. Please guide me how to solve this i have to maintain more folder for other works i can't put cake in root. Thanks

Comment: Have you change the 3 .htaccess you need to modify?

Comment: @Nunser will you please tell me locations of these file. i have changed 2 .htaccess files. One in the Main folder('cake') and one in 'cake/app' folder. I Think the name of the containing folder may create confusion as it also have cake folder inside it.

Comment: the three are in `your-cake-folder`, `your-cake-folder/app` and `your-cake-folder/app/webroot`. If it does not work, you should update the question with the 3 files to see what you have and may be causing the problem.

Comment: @Nunser thanks for your time. I have found the solution to this problem.

Comment: Glad you found the solution :) Could you mark your answer as accepted so the rest know you've found the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change or update any `.htaccess` file in the folder just have to comment this line in `core.php`

```
//Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

and this solves the problem. Leave all the `.htaccess` files as it as. Hope this will help others too.